# extending customstringconvertible across collections

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I've implemented a linked list in swift - I've also built a stack and queue that both use the linked list under the hood. I extended my linked list to conform to the customstringconvertible protocol so I can call print(list) on it. The extension is included in my linkedlist.swift file, and is as follows :

```
extension LinkedList: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var currentIndex: Int = 0
        var description: String = ""
        if var currentNode = self.head {
       // while currentNode != nil {
            for _ in 0...count-1 {
                //description += (String(currentNode.value) + " " )
                description += ("\"" + (String(currentNode.value)) + "\"" + " is at index: \(currentIndex)\n")
                if let nextNode = currentNode.next {
                currentNode = nextNode
                currentIndex += 1
            }
            }
        }
        return description
}
}
```

How can I extend this functionality to my queue/stack without having to rewrite the protocol extension? My queue file looks like this:

```
class Queue <T> {
    private var list = LinkedList<T> ()
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return list.isEmpty
    }
```

followed by whatever functions I chose to implement. Calling print(newQueue) in a VC or elsewhere never calls the linkedList customstringconvertible extension...not sure why. Do I need to subclass linkedlist as a queue/stack? I'm coming from an Objc background with less focus on protocols and extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Queue` is not a subclass of `LinkedList`, so it does not inherit
the `description` property. You'll have to implement the protocol
for that class as well, but of course you can "forward" to the 
description of `LinkedList`:

```
extension Queue: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return list.description
    }
}
```